# Correct way of conditional rendering within a partial in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have created a partial for a `LineItem` that, in my case, emits a `<tr>` with a couple of `<td>`s. This works just fine and dandy.

What I'd want to do then, is use the same partial in different places. The original view has plenty of room, so displaying every cell is ok. But another (a sidebar), has much less space, and I'd only want to display two of the 5 cells.

So the question, then, is what is the correct way of implementing this? I'd like for the "full" version to be the default unless otherwise specified, and only use the limited version if a parameter is passed.

Currently I'd probably use the feature of passing locals to a partial and check if a parameter `limited` is defined, and if so, skip the last N cells. Am I on a right track, and if so, what kind of a variable should I use (can I use symbols for this)?

Current _line_item.html.erb (that I'm somewhat unhappy with)

```
<tr>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price, unit: '€') %></td>
  <% unless defined? limited %>
    <td class="remove_item"><%= button_to 'Remove', line_item, method: :delete %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Edit: Added current version.

Comment: Could you add some code of what you have done that we can copy-paste? I find it very energy consuming to produce an example from scratch. :)

Comment: Sure, there you go :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are on the right track.  You can do something like

```
<%= render 'partial_name', limited: true %>
```

and then in the partial:

```
<% limited ||= false %> # More explicit as to what default value is
<tr>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price, unit: '€') %></td>
  <% unless limited %>
    <td class="remove_item"><%= button_to 'Remove', line_item, method: :delete %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

Comment: Ah of course, I was kind of wondering how to specify that default parameter - this makes perfect sense. Thanks!